# Merge two latex files

Tags: bibliographies

I'm trying to append to the end of my manuscript the supplementary information to form one latex file. The resulting file will of course have two bibliographies, corresponding to the one in the manuscript and the one in the SI separately.

So the manuscript looks like this:

```
\begin{document}

Text_1 (some text with citations)

Bibliography_1

\end{document}
```

The supplementary information looks like this

```
\begin{document}

Text_2 (some other text with citations)

Bibliography_2

\end{document}
```

Now, I want to merge the two into one latex file that will output this:

Text_1

Bibliography_1

Text_2

Bibliography_2

Could anyone show me how to write this?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the "supplementary information"? How do you intend to fuse those files? I think it's unclear what you ask

Comment: supplementary information = appendix

Comment: related: e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364627/how-can-i-put-parts-of-a-bibliography-at-an-arbitrary-place-in-the-document

Comment: please edit your question, explaining what you have in each file, what you intend to do, and what is the problem. As it stands I think it's hard to answer

Comment: I included additional information. Is it clear now?

Comment: No. Please try to make something like [minimal but working examples with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography?s=1|1.0354) at least of the documents you want to merge. We need, e.g., information about how you made the bibliographies (`bibtex` or `biblatex`, same styles or different, …).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

One can simply use the `chapterbib` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}

\input{file1}

\input{file2}

\end{document}
```

It is important that one runs pdflatex on the main file first and then bibtex on file1.tex and then file2.tex before running pdflatex twice on the main file.