# merging TEX file form my gitlab in a live connectivity

Tags: overleaf

I have multiply tex files in different libraries within my gitlab account

I am trying to create one tex file which will "pull" other tex files upon creation. the other tex files are located like this:

(example:https://gitlab.com/XXX/-/blob/master/Documents/XXXXXX/maximum.tex)

How can I merger few tex files like this so the merged tex file will be updated with the other updated tex files?

I checked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365541/merge-two-latex-files?newreg=98c9e507befb4ad3a4fe8c3a2adc9505) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) but couldn't find how to make it "live" connection.

pls advice,

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5433/can-i-use-an-image-located-on-the-web-in-a-latex-document (so the workflow is 1. download the file from within your tex code by calling a system command that does the downloading and 2. input or include this file immediately after).

Comment: Note that with Overleaf it may be a bit more difficult to execute system commands because they understandably do not allow arbitrary things to be executed on their servers - installing and running LaTeX on your local system may be necessary for this approach to work.

Comment: this is showing how to get a png file not a tex file. do I need to use "\write18{wget https://gitlab.com/XXX/-/blob/master/Documents/XXX.tex}" and than \include ?

Comment: Yes, exactly - you could also write a small macro that combines the two steps, but first it would be good to check if this approach actually works in your situation.

Comment: wget returns an error... I am a newbie with this, could you pls share a macro like this?

Comment: Are you trying on Overleaf or on your local computer? If it is on Overleaf, then this might not be allowed, you should ask Overleaf support to check. If it is on your local computer then your operating system may be the issue. `wget` is a Linux program, if you use Windows then you need to use different tools (see https://superuser.com/questions/25538/how-to-download-files-from-command-line-in-windows-like-wget-or-curl) in your `\write18` line.